# Draw rectangles in a cartesian coordinate system

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, data-visualization, coordinate-systems

I want to draw a following chart in JavaScript. Basically, the goal is to draw some rectangles in a cartesian coordinate system. Each rectangle can be represented by 4 points, whose coordinates are given.

Does anyone know how to draw it? Is there any library to do so? Ideally, i would expect some example code that I could adjust a little bit, rather than drawing everything from scratch.

[image]

Comment: You can use the HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Thank you, could you provide any code? @SpencerWieczorek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main options:

- SVG - vector graphics that are pretty similar to HTML (you have elements with attributes etc). you can also use CSS for styling SVG.
- canvas - this is basically a bitmap on which you can draw with JS.
- (HTML) - of caurse you could also use simple HTML + CSS.

Here are some tutorials about those two:

- http://svgtutorial.com/manipulating-svg-with-javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

There are bunch of 3rd party libraries to help with this like:

- https://d3js.org/
- http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/
- http://fabricjs.com/
- http://paperjs.org/

Here is simple example with canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
ctx.strokeRect(0, 200 - 20, 20, 20);
ctx.strokeRect(30, 200 - 70, 20, 70);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but could you provide one library or one existing example that matches best what I am after? (ideally, i would just need to modify a little bit the code, rather than drawing from scratch)

Comment: And then, I need to draw a cartesian coordinate system on top of those rectangles?

Comment: Yes, when using canvas, you need to do everything on your own. You will need to use some 3rd party library if you do not want to do it. d3.js is kind of overkill I think, depends on what you want in the end... Here is example of drawing simple x/y axis with d3.js: https://codepen.io/Dentz/pen/qZVZwB

Comment: can you explain the fifth argument of `strokeRect ` didn't find any reference for it.

Comment: There are only 4 parameters